# Jmeter samples Ok and Ko doesnot match

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have run a web test and successfully generated the Apdex report but I see the Ok and Ko counts doesn't match. There are 10 transactions in my case, when I SUM the OK count of transaction-2 with KO count of transactions-1, it doesn't match with the transaction-1 OK count  what could be the issue i made here?

I have a jssr assertion in one of the transaction2 sampler. Let me know if any other detailed information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing:

1. Your [Thread Group(s) configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or even better schematic export of your Test Plan (Tools -> Generate Schematic View)

   [image]
2. Your [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
3. Your [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)
4. Ideally your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

Given you have defined number of threads/loops your assumption is not very correct, in this case the number of `transaction-1 OK requests plus transaction-1 KO requests` must be equal to  `transaction-2 OK requests plus transaction-2 KO requests` and its turn must be equal to `10`